# CloudDeploy and printing DateListPlot

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I  work with the following dataset:

```
testdata = {{DateObject[{2017, 1, 1}, "Day"], 486, 1, 
   2}, {DateObject[{2017, 1, 2}, "Day"], 487, 2, 
   3}, {DateObject[{2017, 1, 3}, "Day"], 487, 3, 
   4}, {DateObject[{2017, 1, 4}, "Day"], 486, 4, 
   5}, {DateObject[{2017, 1, 5}, "Day"], 487, 5, 
   6}, {DateObject[{2017, 1, 6}, "Day"], 4851, 6, 7}};
```

I want to make a interactive graph in the cloud. To make the graph interactive I create the next 'choose-option':

```
head = {"nr1" -> 2, "nr2" -> 3, "nr3" -> 4};
```

The next CloudDeploy works fine:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{ "kop" -> {head} -> 2},
  DateListPlot[
    TimeSeries[Map[Flatten, testdata, {-4}][[All, {1, #kop}]]]
    , PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}
    , PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Wide", "Sans"}
    ] &
  ], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

Now I want to make some improvements, for example to plot also the 'max', the 'mean', etc.

max=MovingMap[Max,testdata,10];
mean=MovingMap[Mean,testdata,{9,Center},None];
stddev=MovingMap[StandardDeviation,testdata,{9,Center},None];

My first attempt:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{ "kop" -> {head} -> 2},
  testdata1 = 
   TimeSeries[Map[Flatten, testdata, {-4}][[All, {1, #kop}]]] &;
  DateListPlot[testdata1,
   , PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}
   , PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Wide", "Sans"}
   ]
  ], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

this is going wrong. I get two messages:

The expression {1,#kop} cannot be used as a part specification.
TimeSeries[Map[Flatten,testdata,{-4}][[All,{1,#kop}]]]& is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

What is the sollution for this problem?

Comment: The second argument to `FormPage` should be a function. You have `(timeSeriesFunction_; plot_)` but it should be `(timeSeriesFunctionBody_; plot_ )&`

Comment: Thanks, Something goes wrong when I ad PlotLegend. Do you understand why? CloudDeploy[FormPage[{ "kop" -> {head} -> 2},
  (testdata1 = 
     TimeSeries[Map[Flatten, testdata, {-4}][[All, {1, #kop}]]];
    mean = MovingMap[Mean, testdata1, {2, Center}, None];
    DateListPlot[{testdata1, mean}
     , PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}
     , PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Wide", "Sans"}
     , PlotLegends -> {"testdata1", "mean"}
     ]) &
  ], Permissions -> "Public"]

Comment: Plots with legends don't have Graphics head but Legended :-/ and Legended has different export for I guess, you can force it to be e.g. svg: `ExportForm[Module[{testdata1, mean},
  testdata1 = 
   TimeSeries[Map[Flatten, testdata, {-4}][[All, {1, #kop}]]]; 
  mean = MovingMap[Mean, testdata1, {2, Center}, None]; 
  DateListPlot[{testdata1, mean}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Wide", "Sans"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"testdata1", "mean"}]
  ]
 , "SVG"
 ]`

Comment: Hi Kuba, Can you wrote a shore note how you combine 'ExportForm' with 'FormPage'.  I thought : CloudDeploy
[FormPage[{"kop" -> {head} -> 2},
  ExportForm[
   Module[{testdata, mean},
     testdata = 
      TimeSeries[Map[Flatten, testdata, {-4}][[All, {1, #kop}]]]; 
     mean = MovingMap[Mean, testdata, {2, Center}, None]; 
     DateListPlot[{testdata, mean}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
      PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Wide", "Sans"}, 
      PlotLegends -> {"testdata1", "mean"}]] &, "SVG"
   ]]], but this is not working.

Comment: You need to move `&` outside `ExportForm` the second argument is supposed to be a function

Comment: Great. Big Help!!

Comment: Have you managed to make it working? If so, would you mind posting an answer?